# WPBakery css not coming through to content template output pages

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, visual-composer, wpbakery

I am trying to write my custom css in WPBakery on wordpress but nothing shown through the output page and every changes ignored on it.

I hope someone can give me a hint. How can I programatically get the CSS code that WPBakery creates for a page's design options?